# What flaws can be found in my Teensy 4.1 Break Out Board for Mini Sumo Robot schematic?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, voltage-regulator, teensy, terminal-block

My schematic is divided in 4 different parts for easy understanding. First off, we have the power supply, it is composed of a screw terminal where the positive and negative end of a 3 cell, 11.1v LiPo battery will be placed. I have attached a LED after a resistor to serve as a power status light. This will serve as the power supply for the 5V regulator. The regulator section is composed of a 7805 (SOT-89 Form) voltage regulator. It has 0.1uF capacitor in its input and output as it is widely suggested, I plan to use the ceramic type. The regulator will supply the Teensy with a stable voltage that is within the manufacturer's specifications. Finally, I have the screw terminals for the analogs I/O pins. This will allow to perform an easy connection from sensors or other devices to the teensy.

A mini sumo can't be no bigger than 100mm in width and 100mm in length. My board must fit inside so we're trying to keep it in 90mm length x 50mm width, but I can further adjust as design changes. I also plan to implement power supply ports for our infrared sensors, they're 6 Sharp GP2Y0A21YK0F, each with a positive and negative end cable. Also planning to implement DC motor drivers to my board so I can control 2 DC motors from the supply of the battery. Is still a work in progress but I hope to receive the right feedback and consultation to have a working schematic.

[image]

Comment: I think you might have thermal issues with the 7805. You really want a switchedmode supply methinks.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your feedback. Any other issues or warning I should be aware about before I green light the components already selected and how they are wired?

Comment: Apart from the regulator and connectors, there’s not much else.why don’t you build it on dot board first before doing a pcb?

Comment: Will try. Thanks!

Comment: A Teensy 4.0 would work just as well while taking up less space.